# How to agg a column to get standard dev in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which I groupBy Date and name and I aggregate the average of price.

```py
 df.filter("some filter")
    .withColumn("price_int", df.print.cast('integer')) 
    .groupBy("Date", 'name')
    .agg(avg(col('price_int')))
```

I want to get the max, and stddev of price_int column.

```
 df.filter("some filter")
    .withColumn("price_int", df.print.cast('integer')) 
    .groupBy("Date", 'name')
    .agg(avg(col('price_int'),
 max(col('price_int'),
 stddev(col('price_int'),
 )))
```

But when I add `max(col('price_int)`, I get error saying `Column is not iterable`
And when I add `stddev(col('price_int)`, I get error saying 'stdev is not defined'

Can you please tell me how can I get 'max' and 'standard dev' of the column 'price_int'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm skeptical about where the issue is, as the code you provided seems to have syntax messed up, but in any case - the below would work:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.filter("some filter")
    .withColumn("price_int", df.print.cast('integer')) 
    .groupBy("Date", 'name')
    .agg(F.avg(F.col('price_int')).alias("Average"), F.stddev(F.col("price_int")).alias("Std_Deviation"), F.max(F.col("price_int")).alias("Maximum"))
```

Worked for me:

[image: Input/Output]

Also, note Spark has 2 different standard deviation functions:

> stddev() or stddev_samp() - returns the unbiased sample standard
> deviation of the expression in a group
>
> stddev_pop() - returns population standard deviation of the expression
> in a group.